# Python's datetime.datetime.timestamp() is inaccurate/inconsistent with Discord

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, momentjs

## Original Question

I am recently working on datetimes that were far in the past, say, 200 AD. Using `datetime.datetime(200, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).timestamp()`, I got a timestamp of `-55855785600`. However, when I used online timestamp generators, they gave me a timestamp of `-55855813002`.

When I pasted both timestamps into Discord, it showed:

| Datetime | Result | Result (Adjusted to UTC+0) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| My timestamp - `<t:-55855785600:T>` | `7:36:42 AM` | `23:36:42 AM` the last day |
| Their timestamp - `<t:-55855813002:T>` | `8:00:00 AM` | `0:00:00 AM` |

(I live in UTC+8)

This 23-minute-18-second inaccuracy also occurred for datetimes of 161 AD, so I assume it is not a problem with leap years.

Is there something wrong with my code? Are there multiple systems of UNIX Epoch Times which caused this incident? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

## Edit

I have just looked into the source code of the timestamp generator website and realised that they were using moment.js. I tried moment.js' `moment().unix()` and the timestamp was accurate. Is there any difference between the Python and Javascript timestamp calculators?

Comment: You'll need to set a time zone to get comparable results. If you don't, Python's naive datetime will be *local time* (your OS setting), not UTC for example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your local time zone, you should rely on UTC, because some calculations are wrong, here you can see some examples:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timezone


if __name__ == '__main__':
    years = [2000, 1950, 1894, 1893, 200]
    for year in years:
        dt1 = datetime(year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
        dt2 = datetime(year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
        diff = dt2.timestamp() - dt1.timestamp()
        print(f"Year: {year}")
        print(f"{dt1.timestamp()}   {dt1.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')}")
        print(f"{dt2.timestamp()}   {dt2.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')}")
        print(f"dif: {diff}")
        print()
```

And output:

```
Year: 2000
946684800.0   01.01.2000 00:00:00
946681200.0   01.01.2000 00:00:00
dif: -3600.0

Year: 1950
-631152000.0   01.01.1950 00:00:00
-631155600.0   01.01.1950 00:00:00
dif: -3600.0

Year: 1894
-2398291200.0   01.01.1894 00:00:00
-2398294800.0   01.01.1894 00:00:00
dif: -3600.0

Year: 1893
-2429827200.0   01.01.1893 00:00:00
-2429830408.0   01.01.1893 00:00:00
dif: -3208.0

Year: 200
-55855785600.0   01.01.200 00:00:00
-55855788808.0   01.01.200 00:00:00
dif: -3208.0
```

Here the turning point is 1893/1894 (for me).
These bugs are known ([here](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/462) and [here](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/pull/1091))

Comment: I suspect your local time's UTC offset is one hour, and there is not time zone rule definition before 1894, so it falls back to LMT?

Comment: Thank you! I just used a similar method and found out that my turning point was 1904/1905. Unfortunately, I tried your code and it did not help. Thanks for your contribution though!

Comment: What exactly is your problem? -55855785600 is the correct value of your searched date in utc. So if you try to get your date as timestamp online you will get these numbers (if you specifiy utc). If you can not specify utc the online calculators give you local time and so you have this gap, so if you specifiy utc on date_to_timestamp but no utc on timestamp_to_date you get different values online.i tried with https://www.epochconverter.com and https://timestamp.online.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not what happens for Discord.